# Js/Jquery bind Datatable or Datalist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, datatable

**Scenario**

I have a input box for post codes. When you put in a postcode it makes a call to a web service and gets all the suburb names back and binds them to a list, like an input dropdown list.

This works when I return a `List<string>` from the web service for just the names. No problem.

The problem arises when I go to save the values to the db. When it gets saved I cannot save the name of the suburb in the suburb column in the db. I have to save the id of that suburb for the foreign key constraint.

So then I changed the `List<>` thing slighty and cheated and returned the following.

```
<ArrayOfString>
<string>8213</string>
<string>BROOKFIELD</string>
<string>8214</string>
<string>CHAPEL HILL</string>
<string>8215</string>
<string>FIG TREE POCKET</string>
```

etc....

The reason for this is so I can have the `value` of the item in the drop down as the id and hence can save that in the code behind on save.

To do this, I did the following:

```
$(result).each(function (index, value) {

            var suburbname;

            var pattern = new RegExp('[0-9*]');
            var m = pattern.exec(value);

            if (m == null) {
                suburbname = value

                var o = new Option(suburbname, suburbid);
                /// jquerify the DOM object 'o' so we can use the html method
                $(o).html(suburbname);
                $(document.getElementById('<%= suburb.ClientID %>')).append($("<option></option>")
                                                                .attr("value", suburbid)
                                                                .text(suburbname));

            }
            else {
                suburbid = value
            }
```

That works as well... the drop down only has name and the value for those is the number

**The problem....?**

I am making assumptions above which I don't like... I.e. that the name never has a number it, that the web service will always return the id first to set the id before running the add to the dropdown for the first time. *It just feels wrong*.... :S  (thoughts?)

So, if I change the web service to return a datatable, to out the following (which is what the whole query returns):

```
<Suburbs diffgr:id="Suburbs1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<SuburbID>8213</SuburbID>
<SuburbName>BROOKFIELD</SuburbName>
<StateID>4</StateID>
<StateCode>07</StateCode>
<CountryCode>61</CountryCode>
<TimeZones>10.00</TimeZones>
<Postcode>4069</Postcode>
</Suburbs>
```

Is there a way of acheiving the same as above in js/jquery. So when the user inputs the postcode the webservice returns the datatable and then binds it to the select with the SuburbID going into the `value` and the name going into the text???

Any other ways I could return the data from the web service to solve this?

Note: essentially I need the option to look like this:

```
<option value="8213">BROOKFIELD</option>
```

I also thought I could make a second call to get just the id on the bind of the text... but I kind of want to only make one call....

Thanks in adance,

Cheers
Robin

.net, C#, js, jquery, web service.....

**Solution with guidance from Billy**

The adding to the select using the other method below did not work, but my original way did once I had the correct variables so just used that....

The service returns:

```
<ArrayOfMyClass>
<MyClass>
<ID>8213</ID>
<Name>BROOKFIELD</Name>
</MyClass>
```

... etc

The js is: (note: it is `onchange` of the postcode input box. it runs a web service and then on success runs the following)

```
function OnCompleted(result) {

        var _suburbs = result;
        var i = 0;

        $(_suburbs).each(function () {
            var SuburbName = _suburbs[i].Name;
            var SuburbID = _suburbs[i].ID;

            $(document.getElementById('<%= suburb.ClientID %>')).append($("<option></option>")
                                                               .attr("value", SuburbID)
                                                                .text(SuburbName));
            i = i + 1;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your webservice to return that (or any subset that contains at least the id and the name) :

```
<Suburbs diffgr:id="Suburbs1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<SuburbID>8213</SuburbID>
<SuburbName>BROOKFIELD</SuburbName>
<StateID>4</StateID>
<StateCode>07</StateCode>
<CountryCode>61</CountryCode>
<TimeZones>10.00</TimeZones>
<Postcode>4069</Postcode>
</Suburbs>
```

Than use your javascript foreach like such :

```
var root = $('#<%= suburb.ClientID %>');

$(result).each(function (index, value) {

    var row = $(value)[0];

    $('<option></option>')
        .attr('value', $('SuburbID', row).text())
        .text($('SuburbName', row).text())
        .appendTo(root);
}​);
```

**EDIT :** here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rRqJa/2/